# bash shell script to run imgcmp on two JPGs and store 'different' ones

Tags: bash, file, shell, variables

I've got an IP camera that ftps files to a directory on my SuSE server.

I'm trying to write a shell script to do the following:

```
for every file in a directory;
    use image compare to check this file against the next one
    store the output in a file or variable.
    if the next file is different then  
        copy the original to another folder
    else 
        delete the original
end for
```

Running the following at the prompt generates this:

```
myserver:/uploads # imgcmp -f img_01.jpg -F img_02.jpg -m rmse > value.txt
myserver:/uploads # cat value.txt
5.559730
5.276747
6.256132
myserver:/uploads #
```

I know there's loads wrong with the code, the main issue I've got is with executing imgcmp from the script and extracting a value from it, so please point out the obvious as it may not be to me.

```
FILES=/uploads/img*
declare -i value
declare -i result
value = 10
shopt -s nullglob
# no idea what the above even does #
# IFS=.
# attempt to read the floating point number from imgcmp & make it an integer
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "doing stuff w/ $f"
  imgcmp -f 4f -F 4f+1 -m rmse > value.txt
  # doesn't seem to find the files from the variables #
  result= ( $(<value.txt) )
  if [ $result > $value ] ; then
    echo 'different';
    # and copy it off to another directory #
  else
    echo 'same'
    # and delete it #
  fi
  if $f+1 = null; then
    break;
  fi
done
```

when running the above, I get an error `cannot open /uploads/img_023.jpg+1`
and doing a cat of value.txt shows nothing, so all the files show as being the same.

I know where the issues are, but I've got no idea what I should actually be doing to extract the output of imgcmp (run from within a script) and then get it into a variable that I can compare it with.

Comment: You have some typos (4f instead of $f). Have you tried to use basename to extract the filename, play with sed to extract the numeric part of the name, and recombine it ?

Comment: `if [ $result > $value ]` won't work. Use `-gt` instead of `>` for "greater than" comparison. `>` is used for stdout redirection; it will create a file named as the content of `$value` and the `if` test will always succeed.

Comment: Thanks Costi, I'll give that a go and come back. I tried -gt before in there, as I read that was what it wanted, but it gave me an error saying it expected something else ?sorry can't remember what, but I'll give that a go and post something useful back i.e. 'hey it works now', or 'I've got no idea what I'm doing as it says X'. Really appreciate the help. Richard

Comment: `-gt` only works on integers; you may use `bc` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILES=/uploads/*

current=
for f in $FILES; do
  if [ -z "$current" ]; then
    current="$f"
    continue
  fi
  next="$f"
  echo "<> Comparing $current against $next"
  ## imgcmp will return non-0 if images cannot be compared
  ## and print an explanation message to stderr;
  if result=$(imgcmp -f $current -F $next -m rmse); then
    echo "comparison result: " $result
    ## Checking whether the first value returned
    ## is greater than 10
    if [ "$(echo "$result" | awk '$1 > 10 {print "different"}')" = "different" ]; then
      echo 'different';
      # cp -v $current /some/other/folder/
    else
      echo 'same'
      # rm -v $current
    fi
  else
    ## images cannot be compared... different dimensions / components / ...
    echo 'wholly different'
    # cp -v $current /some/other/folder/
  fi
  current="$next"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Costi, you are a star. I've been playing w/ sed awk and cut all morning and either get the syntax wrong, or the exact same characters (i.e. three lines of floating point numbers out). I'll give this a crack after lunch and come back to you. I think I must just be a numpty these days, I know the logic of what I'm trying to do, but my old brain just can't interpret it ;€)

Comment: Hi Costi, that's spot on with the logic, and it works a treat, but... I didn't specify what 'different' meant. when imgcmp compares two pictures of the same thing taken at two different times, it tends to give three values of around 3.something to 6.something, so I'd like to compare the first value of $result with 10/10.0 to determine if it's 'interesting'.  I was trying to do that w/ sed earlier, but it seems I'm too dim.  Thanks for all your help and the loan of your brain, really appreciated.

Comment: Hi Costi, Apologies for not getting back sooner - just in the process of clearing our house for some (minor) earthquake repairs. I've run that against a batch of images, and it looks like it's doing it. I'll have more of a play on Friday once I've got all my bookshelves unloaded, off walls and everything else cleared into our garage much fun :€S Thanks for all your effort on this :€)